# Nonlinear differential equation $u''(r) = (r^2 -3) u(r)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to solve the following equation, this being a form of the Schrodinger equation for the harmonic oscillator, E=3 being the 1st energy level:

$u''(r) = (r^2 - 3) u(r)$

I am going trough a book on numerical analysis and this is solved with the Numerov method, the exact solution is only cited:

$A r e^{-r^2/2}$

How would I go about obtaining this solution? I tried Laplace transforms but this being a nonlinear equation, that method won't work, even Mathematica failed me

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would try first some form like $u(r) = e^{f(r)}$ or $u(r) = g(r) e^{f(r)}$ and try to take 2 derivatives and fit the ODE. Another way is to try with series $u(r) = \sum a_nr^n$ and imposing ODE to get a constraint on $a_n$

Comment: What book is it ?

Comment: The equation is linear.

Comment: This is Weber differential equation

Comment: @md2perpe  The DE has variable coefficients

Comment: @user577215664. It is still linear. If $u$ is a solution and $c$ a constant then $cu$ is also a solution, and if $u_1, u_2$ are solutions then $u_1+u_2$ is also a solution.

Comment: This is a linear second order ODE, well known for harmonic oscillator.

Comment: yes, the equation is linear, you are right, this what it's called is differential equation with variable coefficients because of r squared term

Comment: Substituting $u=e^{\phi_0}$ gives $\phi_0''+(\phi_0')^2=r^2-3$. Substituting $\phi_0'=-r+\phi_1'$ to eliminate the $r^2$ term gives $\phi_1''+(\phi_1')^2-2r\phi_1'+2=0$. Since $\phi_1'=\frac{1}{r'}$, we have $\frac{d\phi_1'}{d\phi_1}=-\frac{r''}{(r')^2}\implies \phi_1''=\frac{d\phi_1'}{d\phi_1}\phi_1'=-\frac{r''}{(r')^3}$. Writing the equation in $r$ gives $-r''+r'-2r(r')^2+2(r')^3=0$. Substituting $r'-r=\phi_2(r)\implies r'-r''=-\phi_2'(\phi_2+r)$ gives $-\phi_2'(\phi_2+r)+2(\phi_2+r)^2\phi_2=0\implies \phi_2=0\implies \phi_1=\ln|r|+C$. Thus, we get $u=Cre^{-r^2/2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the operators $Q$ and $D$ by $(Qf)(r) = r f(r)$ and $(Df)(r) = f'(r).$ Note that $[D,Q] = DQ-QD = 1.$

Let $L = Q^2-D^2.$ The equation can then be written $Lu = 3u.$

Now set $A_- = Q-D$ and $A_+ = Q+D.$ Note that $L = A_- A_+ +1$ and that $[L, A_-] = 2 A_-.$

Let $u_0$ be a solution to $A_+ u_0 = 0,$ i.e. to $r u_0(r) + u_0'(r) = 0.$ This equation is trivial to solve; the solutions are $u_0(r) = C e^{-r^2/2},$ where $C$ is a constant. Note that $L u_0 = (A_- A_+ +1) u_0 = u_0.$

Then let $u_1 = A_- u_0$ and note that
$$
L u_1 = L (A_- u_0) = [L, A_-] u_0 + A_- (L u_0)
= (2 A_-) u_0 + A_- u_0 = 3 A_- u_0 = 3 u_1,
$$
i.e. $u_1$ is a solution to our equation.

Since $u_0(r) = C e^{-r^2/2}$ we have
$$
u_1(r) = r u_0(r) + u_0'(r)
= 2C r e^{-r^2/2}.
$$